# Integrable combinations - I can't seem to arrive at the given answer

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I need help! I can't seem to arrive at the answer given in our textbook. I'm new here, so I really need help.

The instruction says that I need to solve this D.E by recognizing integrable combinations.

$$
y(x^4 e^{xy} - y^2) \, dx + x(x^4e^{xy} + y^2) \, dy = 0 
$$
when $x = 1$, $y = 0$.

And I can't seem to arrive this answer:
$$
y^2 = x^2(1 - e^{xy})
$$

Here is my sol'n:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct:

See **[this page](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%28x%5E4e%5E%7Bxy%7D+-+y%5E2%29dx+%2B+x%28x%5E4e%5E%7Bxy%7D+%2B+y%5E2%29dy+%3D+0)** for proof that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I did not start by looking carefully at your working - I found the handwriting rather offputting. But it looks to me as though you have got the right answer. Here was my derivation.

Start by thinking what happens when you differentiate $e^{xy}$. Rearrange the result onto one side of the equation. On the other side you get $$\frac{y^3dx-xy^2dy}{x^4}$$.

Now consider the advice given of trying to recognize integrable combinations. For example, what happens when you differentiate $$\frac{1}{x^3}$$

You should now be able to integrate both sides. Using the initial condition fixes the integration constant.

However, although it gives something similar to the answer you want, I do not get exactly the same - maybe I made a silly mistake somewhere ...